# AngularJS Animate - Transition To Different Background Color Only Works One Way

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, transition, angular-animations

I use the following CSS to animate the change in background color for a `div`:

```
#availability-button.red-add, #availability-button.red-remove, #availability-button.green-add, #availability-button.green-remove{
    transition: background-color 2000ms linear;
}
#availability-button.red, #availability-button.red-add, #availability-button.red-add-active{
    background-color: #c21807;
}
#availability-button.green, #availability-button.green-add, #availability-button.green-add-active{
    background-color: #68af28;
}
```

The above works only one way - when you transition from green to red.

What is causing this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvm3kepr/2/)

Comment: The fiddle works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `#availability-button.red` and `#availability-button.green`. The animation life-cycle classes like `red-add` and `red-remove` are useful if you're using animations, but for transitions can be tricky since you're just transitioning the *change* in properties between selectors.

In this case, it seems like multiple selectors are matched in the `red-*` and `green-*` groups, which causes undefined behavior in how the transition is completed.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvm3kepr/4/)